# How To do customize code in created new module Of DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

when we create a module into Admin side. and if we want to do customize code into this new module then how can we do this and where this new module file saved? by FTP where can we find this new files of new module.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify what version of DNN you're using. The newest version 5.5.x does more of the work for you in creating new modules than previous versions did.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how new modules in dnn are developed and deployed:

- in your development site, you can login to host and go to host > extensions > create new extension
- follow the wizard to create new extension
- that will create a new module in your ~/DesktopModules folder.
- develop your module and test it in the dev environment
- once you are ready with the release, go to Host > Extensions
- edit your module
- click on create package wiard
- follow the wizard and it will create a new module package (.zip file) which you can install in production environment site.

If you have any other question regarding dnn module development in dnn 5.x feel free to contact me.

Happy dnn devlopment

Answer (score 0):

When you created the module through the module definitions page, one of the things it asked for is the folder name. The module files will be place under the ~/DesktopModules/[yourmodule]/ folder. To modify the files, you'll need to use an external editor of some form. In the Module Controls section of the Module Definition page, you'll be able to select any ascx file within the folder that you specified for the module.

Comment: thank you for response but still i have problem. because new module will placed under /DesktopModule folder but this folder have subfolders also. and we have to create a subfolder for our new module. and when we create new folder then there is no option to select this folder at the time of creatinf new module by admin. please suggest.

Comment: I've added additional detail to my answer. Hopefully this will help.